# How to represent and filter related data model in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I've been struggling to get the desired output based on a simple data model. Can someone take a look and set me on the right track?

I am modeling a custom "group-based permission" schema to a list of Requisitions. I have one table to store a list of Groups, one table to store "membership" (GroupMembership) to Group(s) and a table to store what permissions (Read/Write) Group(s) have to a Requisition (ReqGroups). I even tried the database-first approach using the .NET framework, which is how I generated the DB diagram. This resulted in circular reference errors when I used the generated models in my .NET Core API project. 
[image: Screenshot of data model]

I can represent the desired output via a T-SQL easily:

```
SELECT r.*, x.Rights FROM Requisition r
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT rp.RequisitionID, rp.Rights from ReqGroup rp
   INNER JOIN GroupMembership m on m.GroupID = rp.GroupID
   WHERE m.UserId = @UserId
) x on r.Id = x.RequisitionID
```

Through a lot of trial and error, I was able to get the data from EF with this query:

```
_context.Requisition
  .Include("ReqGroups.Group.GroupMemberships")
  .ToListAsync();
```

But then I need to filter on the related data (GroupMembership) which doesn't seem possible with EF Core. The only alternative I see is to reverse the relationships in the model so I can filter GroupMembership UserId based on the current user and Include Requisition(s).

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, should be possible. Something like:

```
var query = _context.Requisition
    .Where(x => x.ReqGroup
        .Any(rg => rg.Group.GroupMembership.UserId == userId)
    .Select( x => new 
    {
        Requisition = x,
        UserReqGroupRights = x.SelectMany(x => x.ReqGroup
            .Where(rg => rg.Group.GroupMemberShip.UserId == userId)
            .Select(rg => rg.Rights)
            .ToList()
    });
```

This returns an anonymous type containing each requisition which has a user-associated group, with a collection of that user's applicable rights.

To return this data to a view etc. I would recommend selecting into a POCO view model. EF entity relationships cannot be filtered per-se where you could select a requisition and only the associated groups with that user, but you can use `Select` to filter that data.